# Using Alias in SQL with a like statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple question: in this code I can't use the alias and I don't know why.

```
tblSaida AS (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                [FI].COD_Regional,
                [FI].COD_Filial,
                [FI].Nom_Abvd_Filial
                FROM
                COR_Filial [FI]
                    INNER JOIN
                tblFiliais [F]
                    ON
                [FI].COD_Regional = [F].COD_Regional
                AND [FI].COD_Filial = [F].COD_Filial
                AND [FI].Cod_RegionalAtual = @Cod_Regional
                AND [FI].Nom_Abvd_Filial LIKE '%' +  ISNULL(@Filtro, Nom_Abvd_Filial) + '%'   AS [NOM_Regional]
                ORDER BY
                [FI].NOM_Regional

                SELECT 
            [S].COD_Filial,
            [S].NOM_Regional
```

I get error on the 'AS'

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

Can someone help me?

EDIT:

I moved the alias to the select.Now i having error in the like statment

```
tblSaida AS (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                [FI].COD_Regional,
                [FI].COD_Filial,
                [FI].Nom_Abvd_Filial LIKE '%' +  ISNULL(@Filtro, Nom_Abvd_Filial) + '%'   AS [NOM_Regional]
                FROM
```

---

I used the alterations you guys sugested and now it Works.

```
tblSaida AS (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                [FI].COD_Regional,
                [FI].COD_Filial,
                [FI].Nom_Abvd_Filial
                FROM

                COR_Filial [FI]

                    INNER JOIN
                tblFiliais [F]
                    ON
                [FI].COD_Regional = [F].COD_Regional
                AND [FI].COD_Filial = [F].COD_Filial
                AND [FI].Cod_RegionalAtual = @Cod_Regional

                )
                SELECT 
            [S].COD_Filial,
            [S].Nom_Abvd_Filial



        FROM
            tblSaida [S]
             ORDER BY 
      [S].Nom_Abvd_Filial
```

Comment: post the full query to be clear.

Comment: TSql syntax allows no aliases at WHERE  or ON clause.

Comment: I moved the alias to the select,and the error is in the LIKE now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drop the column alias.  `WHERE` clauses are not where you define column aliases.  `SELECT` clauses are for that:

```
[FI].Nom_Abvd_Filial LIKE '%' +  ISNULL(@Filtro, Nom_Abvd_Filial) + '%'
```